# HttpWebRequest PATCH method and JSON gives Bad Request

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to send some data to a REST API.
The documentation of the API tells me that I have to use PATCH, and provide the data as JSON. The API also requires oAuth 2.0 to make the call, so I fetch an access token first and append that to the api url call.

I have the following code:

```
public MyResponse HttpPatch(
        string url,
        string content,
        Dictionary<string, string> headers,
        string contentType = "application/json")
    {

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Uri.EscapeUriString(url));
        if (request == null)
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Could not create the httprequest from the url:{0}", url));

        request.Method = "PATCH";
        foreach (var item in headers)
            request.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value);

        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);

        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        request.ContentType = contentType;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        try
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            return new MyResponse(response);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            HttpWebResponse errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
            return new MyResponse(errorResponse);
        }
    }
```

In the try block, I get an error on .GetResonse, which says "(400) Bad Request".
The values I provide to the method:

url = https://api.myserver.com/v1/users/1234?access_token=my_access_token 
(myserver and my_access_token have real values in my code)

content = lang=fr&nationality=FR&country=FR&first_name=John&last_name=Doe

headers = dictionary with 1 element: {"Authorization", "ApiKey myuser:mykey"} 
(myuser and mykey have real values in my code)

contentType = "application/json"

Is there anything obvious that I'm missing that could explain the "bad request" error? What could be possible reasons for this error?

The access token I use is correct, the endpoint URL is correct.
I'm not sure about the "PATCH" value for method, can I do it like that? Because the MSDN documentation does not mention this in the possible values:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.method(v=vs.110).aspx

Pulling my hair and struggling for 2 days now to get the call working, so hopefully someone can show me the light of give me some good pointers to put me on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working in the end.
Turned out my content type was wrong, since I was not providing json.
After changing it to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and keeping the PATCH value for method, it works now.